# Could not load file or assembly NLog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Error: http://pbrd.co/1vTqOTb

I am getting an error in my XAML in my WPF project:

```
"Error  11  Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=2.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. 
 The system cannot find the file specified. MainWindow.xaml 73  9   TestApp"
```

I have searched the entire solution and cant find any 'NLog'
I have tried to add the NLog dll to each of my projects in the solution but it makes no difference.
Any idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI: The image link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

Turned out to be the NLog was .Net 4.0 and the project was .Net 4.5
I changed the project to 4.0 and the other dependent project to 4.0 and its working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you reference another library, there's the chance they will need some other library. When you reference WPF, there are a lot of underlying libraries that get pulled up.

First, make sure that the DLLs you've referenced are set to "Copy Local = True" under their Properties. Also make sure they have the same PublicKeyToken as your error - if they're referenced by strong name (and most of .NET is) a slightly different version won't be read as the correct file.

The other thing you should consider is checking whether the DLL exists in your GAC, and [manually installing it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx) if it doesn't. This can often be the cause of such frustrating errors due to a misinstalled sdk (I once has the same issue with the Blend libraries)